lock file version `4` was found, but this version of Cargo does not understand this lock file, perhaps Cargo needs to be updated?
error: failed to parse lock file at: /home/meraxix/voting/voting/anchor/Cargo.lock

Caused by:
  lock file version `4` was found, but this version of Cargo does not understand this lock file, perhaps Cargo needs to be updated?

The Cargo.toml is
[package]
name = "voting"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "voting"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []
idl-build = ["anchor-lang/idl-build"]

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.30.1"

all the dependencis are updated

could you also add the versions of solana and anchor CLI?
